# Cropped linestack plot (vegan)

Tags: r, plot, vegan

**Problem:**

I am using the `linestack` plot from the `vegan` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/index.html).
For higher number of data/labels the plot gets cropped.

**Reproducable Example:**

```
library(vegan)
linestack(x= 1:100, labels = 1:100)
```

[image]

**Question:**
How can I get the complete plot including all values/labels (1:13 and 85:100) without crop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two choices. First, you can just make your plotting device larger. If you're drawing to the screen, make the plot window larger and re-run the commands. If you're exporting via `png()` or `pdf()` or something, just make the dimensions larger (taller). Your second option is to make the font size smaller. `linestack` appears to use base graphics so do

```
par(ps=8)
linestack(x= 1:100, labels = 1:100)
```